# Provisioning profile which can be use in all the applications

Tags: provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have iOS developer team and all of they want to install their app into the real device and I want to give them all a single provisioning profile so they need not to change the bundle id of the app. For example, there are two apps say helloWorld and myFirstApp and I want that both these app should use the same profile (without replacing each other).

I know we can create a developer profile having * bundle id which has this same features whatever I'm looking for. Now my question is how to create that profile? Please explain me in little bit more detail.

I know we can never submit an app with such profile i.e. we have to use separate profile for all the app but it can be done for development purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options.

First, if you have a limited set of devices that you need to install to that are known ahead of time, you can use the standard Ad Hoc distribution profile.  This allows you to build on your local Mac to up to 100 devices that have to be defined in the profile ahead of time.  This does not require an Enterprise account - so any Apple developer account can do this.

Second, if you need to distribute your test apps outside of your team, and the devices will change, Apple has an Enterprise Program (your company must have a DUNS number, I believe), that will allow you to create enterprise distributions that can be deployed on any device.  Those builds still have a limited expiration on the provisioning profile and certificate, so they must be re-built / reinstalled occasionally.  In general, this is the method used for broad distribution / beta tests.

For a single team to use a single provisioning profile, I would choose option 1, create the provisioning profile on Apples developer site with all of your devices, and then add all your developers to the team in the dev portal.  Xcode 5/6 will take care of the rest for you if you go into preferences, and add their accounts to the "Accounts" tab.

In older versions of Xcode (4.x and before), you could have one developer create the provisioning profile, and certificates, then export out a .developerprofile from Organizer that would package up the certificate and .mobileprovision files needed to build to your team's devices.